# Creating tags via API

Tags: custom-post-types, tags, api

I'm working on using the WP API to insert posts via AJAX.

What's the proper way of adding tags dynamically to a custom post type? These tags would not be predefined, but rather be created on demand by the user.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
            $tags = explode(" ", $_POST['post_tags']);

        $new_entry = array(
            'post_title' => $_POST['post_title'],
            'post_content' => $_POST['post_content'],
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
            'post_type' => 'customposttype',
            'post_tags' => $tags);

        $created = wp_insert_post( $new_entry );
```

(Yes, this is prototype code and I'm not sanitizing input yet :))

Comment: Just in case you did not see it, I've updated my answer to address an issue called out in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi **@James:**

If you have the post ID of your newly created post *(the `$created` variable from your question)* you use the `wp_set_object_terms()` function, for example:

```
wp_add_post_tags($created,'My First Tag');
wp_add_post_tags($created,'My Second Tag');
wp_add_post_tags($created,'My Third Tag');
```

Comment: You forgot to mention `$append` argument in your example, in current form every call will delete earlier tag. To add all three tags it needs to have `$append` or tags passed as array. There are also couple of simpler and more specific wrappers available - `wp_set_post_tags()` (same mechanics, just omits `$taxonomy`) and `wp_add_post_tags()` (`$append` set to `true`).

Comment: +1 for append - i remember it driving my nuts trying to figure it out

Comment: @Rarst - Good catch.  That's what I get when I try to answer too many questions in a weekend.  I've updated the answer per your suggestions.  PROPs to you and בניית אתרים too.

Comment: Thank you! I went with a slightly different solution: wp_set_post_tags( $created, $tags ); which sets them all at once.

Comment: @James - Yes, with WordPress there are often several ways to accomplish the same goal. Glad I could point you in the right direction.